# How can i remove all fields and values by using key value or a field key from firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: screenshot of data]

```
DatabaseReference dr1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DailyExpenseTable");
dr1.removeValue();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"DailyExpense Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in your question removes the entire `DailyExpenseTable` node, so also all expenses under there.

If you want to remove a single node under it and you know the key of that node, you can remove it with:

```
DatabaseReference dr1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DailyExpenseTable");
dr1.child("-M2QsnCvO7jTtZbXp47s").removeValue();
```

If you don't know the key, but know another property, you can first execute a query and then remove the results of that query with:

```
DatabaseReference dr1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DailyExpenseTable");
dr.orderByChild("dailyExpenseID").equalTo("2").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot expenseSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            expenseSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

In the latter case, you may end up deleting multiple nodes, if multiple expenses can have the same value for `dailyExpenseID`.

If that can never happen, you might want to consider using the `dailyExpenseID` as the key for the child nodes. So store them with:

```
dr1.child(expenseId).setValue(...)
```

Instead of the `dr1.push.setValue(...)` that you now likely use.

Comment: Hey, puf. There's a `.getRef()` call missing. Should be `expenseSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();`.

Comment: Good point Alex. Thanks, and fixed. Feel free to make such edits yourself in the future btw. Yay for the wiki nature of SO. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll do it. Thanks