# Delete FireBase Value Without Knowing The Key Name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am working on the memories Firebase app and there is a stage where the user can upload photos to his memory.  Each photo has uniq name "ImgLink0","ImgLink1",etc..

The function I am working on is to delete a specific photo when I am pressing a long click, but I can't reach the image in Firebase.

I tried like below but I got stuck because I can't identify the image key:

```
mDatabase.child(userUID).child("Memories").child(memoryName).child("Images").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            
            String imagesKey = imageSnapshot.getKey();
            String imagesValue = (String) imageSnapshot.getValue();

            Log.e("Test","" + imagesKey + "" + imagesValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

And this is the data structure:
[image]

I tried using query too but with no success because I don't have the image key.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node from the database, you need to know the completely path to that node.

Assuming you *do* know the URL of the image to delete, but not the key (`ImgLink1` or `ImgLink2`) that is stored under, you're going to have to use a query to look up that key.

Something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child(userUID).child("Memories").child(memoryName).child("Images");
Query query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo("URL of the image")
query..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot imageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {            
            imageSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }
    ...
```

Also see these related answer:

- [deleting specific post in database(by post node) but it deletes entire database_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803390/deleting-specific-post-in-databaseby-post-node-but-it-deletes-entire-database/52803505#52803505)
- [How can i remove all fields and values by using key value or a field key from firebase realtime database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689048/how-can-i-remove-all-fields-and-values-by-using-key-value-or-a-field-key-from-fi/60689125#60689125)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the second URL for example, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference imageToDeleteRef = rootRef
    .child(uid)
    .child("Memories")
    .child("TestMem")
    .child("Images")
    .child("ImgLink1");
imageToDeleteRef.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

So I have created a reference that points exactly to `ImgLink1` node and then I called `.removeValue()` on reference in order to delete it. So there is no need to read the value in order to perform a delete operation.

If you want to read the URL, please use these lines:

```
imageToDeleteRef.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            String url1 = task.getResult().child("ImgLink1").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", url1);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com...
```

Comment: Hey Alex,Thank you very much,that worked but I wanted to delete the value without knowing the key name. Thanks again.